# Serving angular2 from different subdirectory with base href

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, systemjs

I'm serving up independent angular apps in different subdirectories with dotnet core. It's been a blast seeing this thing in action, but I'm running into something that I just don't understand.

My app lives here:

```
wwwroot/
  pap/
    admin/
      boot.ts
      admin.component.ts
```

The MVC route for this app is /pap/admin/. There are two ways I would expect Angular2 routing to work in this situation. The first is to build all of my Angular routes to match the MVC routes. This works, but it feels cheap. The second way is to set the base tag like so:

```
<base href="/pap/admin/">
```

Both of these ways allow me to use server-side and client-side routes independently and without prepending every single route with /panel/admin/. E.g.,

```
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/menu', name: 'Menu', component: MenuComponent, useAsDefault: true }, 
  { path: '/panels/:id', name: 'Panel', component: PanelComponent } 
  ])
```

My issues are with SystemJS. I've experimented, read, searched, and I still don't know what is going on. In the quickstart, the Angular libraries are included in script tags. If I understand it correctly, the app doesn't need to be told where Angular and Rxjs are to be loaded from because they are already included in the document.

The libraries are in node_modules and are being served as if they live in wwwroot/. With , naturally my app starts looking for the files in /pap/admin/angular2/ instead of where they are. If I use this configuration,

```
System.config({
  baseURL: '/',
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  packages: {
    format: 'register',
    'pap/admin': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
  }
});
System.import('/pap/admin/admin.boot.js')
  .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

then the whole thing blows up looking for everything I've ever imported, starting with

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
```

It is looking for it at the root (wwwroot or http://localhost:5000/angular2/platform/browser.js) instead of in /node_modules/angular2/. This makes sense to me, although I don't completely understand why it doesn't use the libraries that I've loaded in the script tags.

If I use

```
System.config({
  baseURL: '/node_modules/',
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  packages: { 
    format: 'register',
    'pap/admin': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
  },
});
System.import('/pap/admin/admin.boot.js')
  .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

the app comes to life. It does so even if I remove the libraries from the script tags. Sure, SystemJS now knows that if I import something from, say, 'angular2/core', that it can look in /node_modules/ to find it. The downside here is that performance is noticeably slower in terms of the initial. Checking the output of dotnet core, I can see that it's loading every file in those libraries. Woops.

I thought if I used baseURL: '/' and mapped the Angular bits to where they live that everything would be fine,

```
map: { angular2: '/node_modules/angular2/' }
```

but the result is the same; every last piece is loaded.

One more thing … SystemJS says they will be getting rid of defaultJSExtensions soon, but once I added  and started wrangling the System.config part, things just wouldn't work without it.

I would appreciate some guidance from anyone who has experience with either SystemJS or building on top of the new dotnet core stuff.

**Edit 1**

I tried getting started with jspm, but as I commented below, either I am doing something crazy, or it is. Here is my config.js after running only jspm install angular2:

```
   System.config({
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "typescript",
  typescriptOptions: {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  paths: {
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"
  },

  map: {
    "angular2": "npm:angular2@2.0.0-beta.9",
    "core-js": "npm:core-js@1.2.6",
    "typescript": "npm:typescript@1.8.7",
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0": {
      "assert": "npm:assert@1.3.0"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0": {
      "buffer": "npm:buffer@3.6.0"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-constants@0.1.0": {
      "constants-browserify": "npm:constants-browserify@0.0.1"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0": {
      "crypto-browserify": "npm:crypto-browserify@3.11.0"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-events@0.1.1": {
      "events": "npm:events@1.0.2"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@0.1.0": {
      "path-browserify": "npm:path-browserify@0.0.0"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2": {
      "process": "npm:process@0.11.2"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-stream@0.1.0": {
      "stream-browserify": "npm:stream-browserify@1.0.0"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-string_decoder@0.1.0": {
      "string_decoder": "npm:string_decoder@0.10.31"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@0.1.0": {
      "util": "npm:util@0.10.3"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-vm@0.1.0": {
      "vm-browserify": "npm:vm-browserify@0.0.4"
    },
    "npm:angular2@2.0.0-beta.9": {
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "es6-promise": "npm:es6-promise@3.1.2",
      "es6-shim": "npm:es6-shim@0.33.13",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
      "reflect-metadata": "npm:reflect-metadata@0.1.2",
      "rxjs": "npm:rxjs@5.0.0-beta.2",
      "zone.js": "npm:zone.js@0.5.15"
    },
    "npm:asn1.js@4.5.2": {
      "assert": "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0",
      "bn.js": "npm:bn.js@4.11.0",
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "minimalistic-assert": "npm:minimalistic-assert@1.0.0",
      "vm": "github:jspm/nodelibs-vm@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:assert@1.3.0": {
      "util": "npm:util@0.10.3"
    },
    "npm:bn.js@4.11.0": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:browserify-aes@1.0.6": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "buffer-xor": "npm:buffer-xor@1.0.3",
      "cipher-base": "npm:cipher-base@1.0.2",
      "create-hash": "npm:create-hash@1.1.2",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "evp_bytestokey": "npm:evp_bytestokey@1.0.0",
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:browserify-cipher@1.0.0": {
      "browserify-aes": "npm:browserify-aes@1.0.6",
      "browserify-des": "npm:browserify-des@1.0.0",
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "evp_bytestokey": "npm:evp_bytestokey@1.0.0"
    },
    "npm:browserify-des@1.0.0": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "cipher-base": "npm:cipher-base@1.0.2",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "des.js": "npm:des.js@1.0.0",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1"
    },
    "npm:browserify-rsa@4.0.1": {
      "bn.js": "npm:bn.js@4.11.0",
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "constants": "github:jspm/nodelibs-constants@0.1.0",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "randombytes": "npm:randombytes@2.0.3"
    },
    "npm:browserify-sign@4.0.0": {
      "bn.js": "npm:bn.js@4.11.0",
      "browserify-rsa": "npm:browserify-rsa@4.0.1",
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "create-hash": "npm:create-hash@1.1.2",
      "create-hmac": "npm:create-hmac@1.1.4",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "elliptic": "npm:elliptic@6.2.3",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "parse-asn1": "npm:parse-asn1@5.0.0",
      "stream": "github:jspm/nodelibs-stream@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:buffer-xor@1.0.3": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:buffer@3.6.0": {
      "base64-js": "npm:base64-js@0.0.8",
      "child_process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-child_process@0.1.0",
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "ieee754": "npm:ieee754@1.1.6",
      "isarray": "npm:isarray@1.0.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:cipher-base@1.0.2": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "stream": "github:jspm/nodelibs-stream@0.1.0",
      "string_decoder": "github:jspm/nodelibs-string_decoder@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:constants-browserify@0.0.1": {
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:core-js@1.2.6": {
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "path": "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@0.1.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:core-util-is@1.0.2": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:create-ecdh@4.0.0": {
      "bn.js": "npm:bn.js@4.11.0",
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "elliptic": "npm:elliptic@6.2.3"
    },
    "npm:create-hash@1.1.2": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "cipher-base": "npm:cipher-base@1.0.2",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "ripemd160": "npm:ripemd160@1.0.1",
      "sha.js": "npm:sha.js@2.4.5"
    },
    "npm:create-hmac@1.1.4": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "create-hash": "npm:create-hash@1.1.2",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "stream": "github:jspm/nodelibs-stream@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:crypto-browserify@3.11.0": {
      "browserify-cipher": "npm:browserify-cipher@1.0.0",
      "browserify-sign": "npm:browserify-sign@4.0.0",
      "create-ecdh": "npm:create-ecdh@4.0.0",
      "create-hash": "npm:create-hash@1.1.2",
      "create-hmac": "npm:create-hmac@1.1.4",
      "diffie-hellman": "npm:diffie-hellman@5.0.2",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "pbkdf2": "npm:pbkdf2@3.0.4",
      "public-encrypt": "npm:public-encrypt@4.0.0",
      "randombytes": "npm:randombytes@2.0.3"
    },
    "npm:des.js@1.0.0": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "minimalistic-assert": "npm:minimalistic-assert@1.0.0"
    },
    "npm:diffie-hellman@5.0.2": {
      "bn.js": "npm:bn.js@4.11.0",
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "miller-rabin": "npm:miller-rabin@4.0.0",
      "randombytes": "npm:randombytes@2.0.3",
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:elliptic@6.2.3": {
      "bn.js": "npm:bn.js@4.11.0",
      "brorand": "npm:brorand@1.0.5",
      "hash.js": "npm:hash.js@1.0.3",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:es6-promise@3.1.2": {
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:es6-shim@0.33.13": {
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:evp_bytestokey@1.0.0": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "create-hash": "npm:create-hash@1.1.2",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:hash.js@1.0.3": {
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1"
    },
    "npm:inherits@2.0.1": {
      "util": "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:miller-rabin@4.0.0": {
      "bn.js": "npm:bn.js@4.11.0",
      "brorand": "npm:brorand@1.0.5"
    },
    "npm:parse-asn1@5.0.0": {
      "asn1.js": "npm:asn1.js@4.5.2",
      "browserify-aes": "npm:browserify-aes@1.0.6",
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "create-hash": "npm:create-hash@1.1.2",
      "evp_bytestokey": "npm:evp_bytestokey@1.0.0",
      "pbkdf2": "npm:pbkdf2@3.0.4",
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:path-browserify@0.0.0": {
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:pbkdf2@3.0.4": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "child_process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-child_process@0.1.0",
      "create-hmac": "npm:create-hmac@1.1.4",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "path": "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@0.1.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:process@0.11.2": {
      "assert": "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:public-encrypt@4.0.0": {
      "bn.js": "npm:bn.js@4.11.0",
      "browserify-rsa": "npm:browserify-rsa@4.0.1",
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "create-hash": "npm:create-hash@1.1.2",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "parse-asn1": "npm:parse-asn1@5.0.0",
      "randombytes": "npm:randombytes@2.0.3"
    },
    "npm:randombytes@2.0.3": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:readable-stream@1.1.13": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "core-util-is": "npm:core-util-is@1.0.2",
      "events": "github:jspm/nodelibs-events@0.1.1",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "isarray": "npm:isarray@0.0.1",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
      "stream-browserify": "npm:stream-browserify@1.0.0",
      "string_decoder": "npm:string_decoder@0.10.31"
    },
    "npm:reflect-metadata@0.1.2": {
      "assert": "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:ripemd160@1.0.1": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:rxjs@5.0.0-beta.2": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:sha.js@2.4.5": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:stream-browserify@1.0.0": {
      "events": "github:jspm/nodelibs-events@0.1.1",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "readable-stream": "npm:readable-stream@1.1.13"
    },
    "npm:string_decoder@0.10.31": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:util@0.10.3": {
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:vm-browserify@0.0.4": {
      "indexof": "npm:indexof@0.0.1"
    },
    "npm:zone.js@0.5.15": {
      "es6-promise": "npm:es6-promise@3.1.2",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    }
  }
});
```

**Edit 2**

While scanning through that list of things that jspm has mapped to in my node library, I noticed this:

```
"npm:angular2@2.0.0-beta.9": {
  "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
  "es6-promise": "npm:es6-promise@3.1.2",
  "es6-shim": "npm:es6-shim@0.33.13",
  "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
  "reflect-metadata": "npm:reflect-metadata@0.1.2",
  "rxjs": "npm:rxjs@5.0.0-beta.2",
  "zone.js": "npm:zone.js@0.5.15"
},
```

Elsewhere I have seen people installing each of these libraries separately, but it looks like installing angular2 pulls in the usual dependencies all on its own now.

Comment: Your question has changed from how to serve Angular2 from another directory to how to install Angular2 with JSPM. My opinion is that, on StackOverflow, when someone provides a helpful answer or fully answers our question, we reward them with up votes or marking the answer as correct. Then we ask a new question based on what we have learned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Shorter Answer

You wrote:

> The libraries are in node_modules.

Do not put them there. Put them inside `wwwroot`. That's where client-side libraries belong. The `node_modules` directory is better for server-side libraries.

## Longer Answer

Are you using [jspm](http://jspm.io/)? That might help. Perhaps experiment with it in a throwaway project, to learn about the standard project structure.

#### Install and Initialize JSPM

```
C:\MyProject> npm install jspm --save-dev
C:\MyProject> jspm init
```

On `jspm init`, accept most of the defaults (by pressing enter.) There is only one non-default for ASP.NET Core.

```
Enter server baseURL (public folder path) [./]:wwwroot
```

#### Install Client-Side Resources

Once you have done the `jspm init`, install client-side resources like this:

```
C:\MyProject> jsmp install angular
C:\MyProject> jspm install bootstrap
```

That will put them into the `wwwroot > jspm_packages > npm` directory and also map them in the `config.js` file.

#### Possible ASP.NET Core Project Structure

Here is a resultant project structure that we have been using (with lots omitted for clarity's sake.)

```
MyProject/
    node_modules/            <-- for server-side tooling
    wwwroot/        
       jspm_packages/        <-- for client-side resources
           github/
               angular   
               components
               twbs
           npm/
               typescript@1.8.7/   
               typescript@1.8.7.js/
       config.js          
    package.json
    project.json    
    Startup.cs
```

#### Possible config.js File

And here is our `config.js`. We can use `baseURL: "/"` because the config.js lives inside our `wwwroot` directory.

```
System.config({                                     
  baseURL: "/",                                     
  defaultJSExtensions: true,                        
  transpiler: "typescript",                         
  paths: {                                          
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*",                 
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*"            
  },                                                

  map: {                                            
    "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "github:twbs/bootstrap@3.3.6",     
    "typescript": "npm:typescript@1.8.7"
  }                                                 
});
```

Good luck. :)

Comment: I haven't tried JSPM yet, so I'll give this a shot and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. If you decide not to use JSPM as your client-side package manager, playing with its `jspm init` generator is still useful. You will will be able to look at its scaffolding, to determine how properly to configure SystemJS. This will help if you use another third party package/build tool, such as gulp/bower.

Comment: I've been working with jspm in a throw-away branch of my project. I have to say, as soon as I typed `jspm install angular2` my config.js became 1,300 lines. I started looking around to see if that was supposed to be the case. I'm pretty sure the answer is no. It's pulling in things like npm:write-file-atomic and npm:win-release.

Comment: Oh. I just looked in my node_modules directory, and it seems to have exploded, too. I'm going to clean that up and get back to you. Ha!

Comment: Yes. If you run `jspm install angular2` then you will install about 100 other dependencies. Perhaps that is because Angular2 is still in beta. Running `jspm install angular` does not have the same thing happen. You're on the bleeding edge. :)

Comment: Just how I like it. ;)

Comment: I got it all up and running with JSPM, as you suggested. While I don't think this solution will find its way into production any time soon (the initial load time is almost 4 seconds), I suspect things will get much better once Angular2 goes to final. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As [@Shaun Luttin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1108891/shaun-luttin) wrote: "Do not put librairies in `node_modules`".

I suggest a solution using `gulp` tasks.

**Put your angular code in a subfolder of your `src` folder**

```
node_modules/
src/
  app/
wwwroot/
```

**Create a `gulpfile.js` containing tasks to compile your `.ts` and copy your source in `wwwroot`**

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var del = require("del");
var tsc = require("gulp-typescript");
var sourcemaps  = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var tsProject = tsc.createProject("tsconfig.json");
var cache = require('gulp-cached');

/**
 * Watch for source file changed.
 */
gulp.task('watch', function ()  {
  gulp.watch("src/**/*", ['compile', 'resources']);
});


/**
 * Compile TypeScript files into wwwroot directory.
 */
gulp.task('compile', function () {
   var tsResult = gulp.src("src/**/*.ts")
        .pipe(cache('compiling'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(tsc(tsProject));
    return tsResult.js
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("wwwroot")); 
});

/**
 * Copy all resources that are not TypeScript files into wwwroot directory.
 */
gulp.task("resources", function () {
    return gulp.src(["src/**/*", "!**/*.ts"])
        .pipe(cache('resourcing'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("wwwroot"))
});

/**
 * Copy all required libraries into wwwroot directory.
 */
gulp.task("libs", function () {
    return gulp.src([
            'es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js',
            'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
            'angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js',
            'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
            'rxjs/bundles/Rx.js',
            'angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js',
            'angular2/bundles/router.dev.js',
            'angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js'
        ], {cwd: "node_modules/**"}) /* Glob required here. */
        .pipe(gulp.dest("wwwroot/lib"));
});

/**
 * Build all.
 */
gulp.task("build", ['compile', 'resources', 'libs'], function () {
    console.log("Building the project ...")
});

/**
 * Default task.
 */
gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

This script use `gulp-cached` to compile and copy only changed files.
There is a `watch` task which watchs for files changed, so you don't need to launch the `build` task each time you modify your code.
The 1st time use `npm build` to build the whole `angular 2` app then use `npm watch`

**The script copy `angular 2` dependencies from `node_modules` folder to the `wwwroot/lib` folder. Configure your `index.html` to use this folder**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>ma freebox blog</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="lib/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>   

    <script src="lib/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app/main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading ...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Configure your `package.json` for `gulp` dependencies:**

```
{
  "name": "your app name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run gulp\" \"npm run lite\" ",    
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "gulp": "gulp",
    "build": "gulp build",
    "watch": "gulp watch",
    "resources": "gulp resources",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.8",
    "systemjs": "0.19.24",
    "es6-promise": "^3.1.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "zone.js": "0.5.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.7",
    "typings":"^0.7.7",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-cached" : "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.12.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0"
  }
}
```

*In this sample I use `lite-server` in the scripts section, it's not mandatory.*

After building the folder structure will be

```
node_modules/
scr/
  app/
wwwroot/
  app/
  lib/
```

Comment: My project is nicely gulpified, but I'm going to look through yours and see if there is anything I want to steal! Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

While packaging things with gulp does seem like the best way to go, since you're going to want to do that anyways, we did find a quick fix for this problem.

Make the base ref point to the subdirectory containing the angular project. This will ensure that all the node_module dependencies are found, etc. Then configure the PathLocationStrategy with a different APP_BASE_HREF so that html5 mode still works for the actual angular app.

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [..... bind(APP_BASE_HREF).toValue("/yardmap/planning")
```

ref: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/APP_BASE_HREF-let.html

ref: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Answer (score 0):

When you're deploying to non-root path within a domain, you'll need to manually update the

```
<base href="/">
```

to

```
<base href="/wwwroot/">
```

in your dist/index.html.

or

Make changes in webpack.common.js

1. Change `balseUrl:'/wwwroot/'` in webpack.common.js
2. add `/wwwroot/` to the links in index.html

Comment: `balseUrl`, or `baseUrl`?